# Why can I access a static variable in another file?

Tags: c, static

I have 2 files:

```
a.c
b.c
```

a.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.c"

int main()
{
    printf("%s", B_VAR);
    return 0;
}
```

b.c:

```
static char B_VAR[] = "Hello world!\n";
```

Compile and run:

```
jonathan:~/code/staticDemo$ gcc a.c -o test
jonathan:~/code/staticDemo$ ./test
Hello world!
```

I was under the impression that static would make `B_VAR` limitted to `b.c` only, yet this seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the `static` keyword makes variables only visible to a single C file. However, in `a.c` you are *including* `b.c` meaning that it is not compiled and linked with a.c, but instead copied into `a.c`.

The C preprocessor copies one file to another when including, and the preprocessor is executed before the file is compiled.

So this is the effective code to be compiled (generated with GCC using the `-e` flag, and excluding the `<stdio.h>` definitions):

```
# 2 "a.c" 2
# 1 "./b.c" 1
static char B_VAR[] = "Hello world!\n";
# 3 "a.c" 2

int main()
{
    printf("%s", B_VAR);
    return 0;
}
```

And this means that `B_VAR` is accessible in `a.c` because it really *is* in `a.c`.

If you instead compiled each separately and linked them together for the final executable, `B_VAR` would *not* be accessible.

Example (`-c` means to only preprocess and compile, but don't link):

`gcc -c a.c -o a.o`
(GCC fails with `use of undeclared identifier 'B_VAR'`)

`gcc -c b.c -o b.o`

`gcc a.o b.o -o test`

`./test`

Hope this helped.

Comment: If I removed static from `B_VAR`, what could I do to make `B_VAR` accessible in `a.c` without the use of a header file?

Comment: Figured it out: I declared `extern char B_VAR[];` in `a.c` and removed `static` from `b.c`

Comment: In larger projects if you wanted to do something similar, you should create a header file corresponding to the source  file that the field is declared in. For this example that would mean declaring ```B_VAR``` in ```b.h``` (with standard include guards), and including ```b.h``` in ```b.c``` and ```a.c```.

Answer (score 0):

The `static` keyword as used there makes a variable local to a "translation unit", not a file.  An `#include` directive pulls all the contents of the named file into the current translation unit.  So yes, `B_VAR` is accessible.

To create a program using multiple translation units, you would skip the `#include "b.c"` and instead give both source files to the compiler driver:

```
$ gcc a.c b.c -o test
```

Normal practice is to never `#include` a source file, only header files. When a project gets more complicated, including a source file via multiple other files will cause multiple definition errors.

Comment: So let's say that `b.c` needed to define `B_VAR`, how would I structure my files so that `a.c` could access `B_VAR`?, I tried removing the `#include "b.c"` and removed the static keyword from `b.c`, but now B_VAR is an undeclared identifier

Comment: It would of course need to be `extern` instead of `static` for that to work. So I'd put `extern char B_VAR[];` in a header file b.h, have both source files `#include "b.h"`, and at the definition in b.c you don't need any `extern` or `static` specifier at all.

Answer (score 0):

The files a.c and b.c are not compiled independently of each other.  You're including b.c inside of a.c.  So what the compiler sees after preprocessing for a.c looks like this:

```
// contents of stdio.h
static char B_VAR[] = "Hello world!\n";

int main()
{
    printf("%s", B_VAR);
    return 0;
}
```

So what `static` actually does it make a variable / function local *to the compliation unit in which is resides* which may consist of one or more source files that are included together.

Had you removed the include and compiled the two files separately, then you would see an error.